# Matching wildcard arrays in PHP - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

PHP code:

```
$search = "Who is KMichaele test";
$array = ["john","michael","adam"];

if (in_array($search, $array)) {
echo "success";
}
else
echo "fail";
```

I want the success output. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to check all the values in `$array` to see if they are present in `$search` in a case-insensitive manner:

```
$search = "Who is KMichaele test";
$array = ["john","michael","adam"];

if (array_reduce($array, 
                 function ($c, $i) use ($search) {
                     return $c || (stripos($search, $i) !== false);
                 },
                 false))
    echo "success";
else
    echo "fail";
```

Output:

```
success
```

**Edit**

Since this is probably more useful wrapped in a function, here's how to do that:

```
$search = "Who is KMichaele test";
$array = ["john","michael","adam"];

function search($array, $search) {
    return array_reduce($array, 
                         function ($c, $i) use ($search) {
                             return $c || (stripos($search, $i) !== false);
                         },
                         false);
}

if (search($array, $search))
    echo "success";
else
    echo "fail";

$search2 = "michael";
if (search($array, $search2))
    echo "success";
else
    echo "fail";
```

Output

```
success
success
```

Comment: @Tenah I have fixed my code so that it works for cases such as "michael" or "michael test".

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `in_array`-esque function that will ignore case and bail early on a match:

```
function search_array($search, $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (stripos($search, $item) !== false) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

$search = "Who is KMichaele test";
$array = ["john", "michael", "adam"];

if (search_array($search, $array)) {
    echo "success\n";
}
else {
    echo "fail\n";
}
```

#### Output

```
success
```

Comment: search = "michael" fail,
search = "michael test"  fail,
search = "test michael" fail,
search = "michaeltest"  fail

Comment: @Tenah good call--`stripos` returns the position, not a boolean. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple regx

```
 $search = "Who is KMichaele test";
 $array = ["john","michael","adam"];
 $regex = '/\b('.implode('|', $array).')\b/i'; 
  ///\b(john|michael|adam)\b/i

 $success = preg_match($regex, $search);
```

The Regex is simple

- \b - matches word boundary
- |  or
- the flag \i, case insensitive

Essential match any of the words in the list.

By using the boundary the word `michael` will not match `kmichael` for example. If you want partial word matches, just remove those.

[Sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/j4FMj7/1) without the word boundry

If you include the 3rd argument

```
  $success = preg_match($regex, $search,$match);
```

You can tell what the matches were.  And last but not lest you can reduce it down to one line

```
 $success = preg_match('/\b('.implode('|', $array).')\b/i', $search);
```